# Como cambiar las comillas invertidas correctamente javascript

Tags: html, ajax, html5, django, table

Estoy Actualizando mis código javascript usando la comillas invertidas en lugar de la comillas simples, me parece mas fácil al leer el código html y javascript, por eso decide usar las comillas invertidas, pero tengo un problema al momento de aplicar las comillas invertidas, resulta que la función format() sus llaves no se cierran y parece que afectan a las demás funciones, quise subir una imagen pero stackoverflow me dice que no puedo subir una imagen del código fuente.

````
 // verificamos si nos esta llegando la informacion de una fila
function format(d) {
    console.log(d);
    var html = '<div>';
    html += '<h4 class="text-center text-info">' + 'Productos vendidos a : '+ ' ' + d.cli.names.toUpperCase() + '</h4>';
    html+='<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    html += '<thead>';
    html += '<tr><th>Producto</th>'
    html += '<th>Categoria</th>'
    html += '<th>Precio</th>'
    html += '<th>Cantidad</th>'
    html += '<th>SubTotal</th></tr>';
    html += '</thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';
    $.each(d.det, function(key, value) {
        console.log(value.prod.name);
    
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>'+value.prod.name+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+value.prod.cat.name+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+value.price+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+value.cant+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+value.subtotal+'</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    }); 
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</div>';
    
    return html;


}

y que se vea algo parecido a esto usando la comillas invertida, el problema que 
tengo es que la llave de la función no solo afecta a este 
código sino a las demás funciones que esta debajo es como 
si la llave que cierra el
 código no cerrara y afecta a la demás funciones

function format(d) {
    // verificamos si nos esta llegando la información de una fila
    console.log(d);
    var html =
        `<div>
            <h4 class="text-center text-info"> Productos vendidos a :  ${d.cli.names.toUpperCase()} </h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Categoria</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>SubTotal</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
todo se me complico al querer pasar este recorrido de objetos, 
esta bien colocar la comillas invertidas ahi o como deberia hacer para poder rellanar lo campos al hacer cada recorrido
               ${$.each(d.det, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(value.prod.name);
                    `<tr>
                        <td>${value.prod.name}</td>
                        <td>${value.prod.cat.name}</td>
                        <td>${value.price}</td>
                        <td>${value.cant}</td>
                        <td>${value.subtotal}</td>
                     </tr>`
                })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>`;
    return html;
}```
````

Comment: La pregunta no plantea un problema de programación en si mismo, sino una cuestion de formato del codigo fuente. No es relevante

Answer (score 0):

la solución que encontré fue trabajarlo de esta manera, esta bien o existe otra forma mas fácil de trabajar con las comillas invertidas, lo que buscaba era  evitar es usar el html+=  para ir agregando partes de código html

```
function format(d) {
    // verificamos si nos esta llegando la informacion de una fila
    console.log(d);
   
    var html =`<div>
    <h4 class="text-center text-info"> Productos vendidos a :  ${d.cli.names.toUpperCase()} </h4>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>SubTotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>`;

    $.each(d.det, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value.prod.name);
        html+=`<tr>
                <td>${value.prod.name}</td>
                <td>${value.prod.cat.name}</td>
                <td>${value.price}</td>
                <td>${value.cant}</td>
                <td>${value.subtotal}</td>
            </tr>`
    });

    html+=`</tbody>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>`;
    
    return html;    
}
```